# How can I figure out where power is coming from in 4-way switch wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

My 4-way switches work correctly.  I would like help figuring out where the power is coming in from and where the light fixture is (at the end, after a certain switch, etc.)  I'm also trying to understand what is happening in this electrical box where "switch B" is housed--there are 4 cables entering the box.  The green line represents the white wire.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Cable 3 goes to switch A.
- Cable 4 goes to switch C.
- Cable 1 goes to the lamp.
- Hot is being supplied to the entire works by the one of the black wires at switch C.
- Neutral is supplied by cable #2.

Supplying hot and neutral in separate locations like that is bizarre and not code legal.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  Those were my guesses, as well.  There is actually another switch in this box whose sole purpose is to provide a ground, because switch B has no ground screw, I suppose.  No other wires are attached to it.

Comment: Where do you think I would find the other end of cable 2?

Comment: Ideally the service panel, but possibly somewhere associated with that rogue black wire at switch C, or potentially anywhere he can find a neutral or ground if he's that sloppy. It sounds like this setup was improvised from an earlier wire configuration, i.e. the switch C site used to be a regular switch loop for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is quite improper & illegal. So, don't touch or change anything unless you're rewiring all of it correctly. The 4-way switch (B) just connects the 2 3-way switches (A & C), it's just a bridge.

FYI, the wires with 3 wires total (black, white & ground) are **supposed to be**  solely for the power supply (C) & light operation (A), just regular Romex cables for in & out. The wires with 4-wires total (black, red, white & ground) are **usually** just the 3-way switch connectors. They aren't **supposed to be** the power supply nor light operator & **should** just transfer the power from 3-way switch to 3-way switch through the 4-way switch.

Your problems are that Regular 3-wire Romex (cable 4) was used to connect (C) to (B), instead of a 4-wire cable (cable 2). And, a proper 4-wire cable (cable 3) was **misused** to connect (A) to (C) while **also** operating the light. Due to these you can't even label things uniformly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and quick response.  I wanted to add another light fixture to this circuit.  Could I still do that, by running cable between the lights?

Comment: Yes, your idea is exactly right. Add another light only by wiring it from the existing light, do not wire anything into the switching wire runs.